# AWS PHP SDK V2 dynamodb - how to disable/enable ssl

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

How do I disable/enable SSL when working with dynamodb with the new PHP SDK (V2).

In V1 there was $DDB->disable_ssl();  Whats the equivalent on V2 ?

Couldn't find anything on this in the documentation.

Comment: Try adding the `ssl.certificate_authority` argument. i.e. `$aws = Aws::factory(array(
  'key' => 'xxxxxxxxxx',
  'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxx',
  'region' => Region::US_WEST_2,
  'ssl.certificate_authority' => true
));`

Answer (score 3):

While it is not recommended, you can disable SSL by passing a `scheme` option to a client's factory method or as a configuration setting in a service builder.

```
<?php

$client = Aws\DynamoDb\DynamoDbClient::factory(array(
  'key'    => '***',
  'secret' => '***',
  'region' => 'us-east-1',
  'scheme' => 'http'
));
```

The `scheme` option determines the URL scheme used when creating the base URL used to contact a service.